# Get the date/time that Sitecore last published

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Simple question, I think:  is there a value, either in the API or the Web database, that will tell me the last time content was published using sitecore?  It looks like there's an "Updated" column in the "Items" table that might do this, but I'd like to be sure.  I don't need to know individual items, just the last time any content was published.

Answer (score 8):

Iff (that's if and only if) the publish is a full site publish or an incremental publish, Sitecore will record that date to the database, and it can be retrieved from the master DB using

```
Database.Properties.GetLastPublishDate(Database target, Language language)
```

Otherwise, if you want the date for **any** publish, you're probably going to need to create a  publish pipeline processor to record that date somewhere.

Comment: Why doesn't this work for a Smart publish?  I usually use that... I never did figure out the difference between incremental and "smart". :|

Comment: Smart compares items to see what needs to be published, incremental uses the publishing queue to track items that have changed, and publishes what's changed since the last incremental publish. The publish date here is used only to track when the last incremental publish was run.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this while looking for something similar. Something like this worked for me:

```
public String PostDate()
{
    DateTime postDate = Context.Item.Statistics.Updated;
    return postDate != null ? postDate.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy H:mm:ss tt") : String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to be when the item was last saved, not published.